# How do i get the oAuthToken from the safe web3modalPack

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk, safe, web3auth

I am building an application where i require the oAuthIdToken returned by web3Auth.userInfo() , but safe account abstraction kit is not returning the google users oauth token.

```
{
  "email": "amanzishan.az@gmail.com",
  "name": "aman zishan",
  "profileImage": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKiDmpRjHKJB44BoPJsumXA7I55JT9CTpnUIm6cW5X1Z8w=s96-c",
  "aggregateVerifier": "tkey-google-lrc",
  "verifier": "torus",
  "verifierId": "amanzishan.az@gmail.com",
  "typeOfLogin": "google",
  "dappShare": "",
  "idToken": "",
  "oAuthIdToken": "",
  "oAuthAccessToken": ""
}
```

web3Auth returns this

```
{
    "email": "amanzishan.az@gmail.com",
    "name": "aman zishan",
    "profileImage": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKiDmpRjHKJB44BoPJsumXA7I55JT9CTpnUIm6cW5X1Z8w=s96-c",
    "aggregateVerifier": "web3auth-core-google",
    "verifier": "web3auth-core-google",
    "verifierId": "amanzishan.az@gmail.com",
    "typeOfLogin": "google",
    "dappShare": "",
    "idToken": "",
    "oAuthIdToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdkMzM0NDk3NTA2YWNiNzRjZGVlZGFhNjYxODRkMTU1NDdmODM2OTMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.DVJsDIqBgnm2xMHyOj4LMpQWLqF5rBfph4TDEdq1w3cOUuYUCoH0I_8AOlAYYA56ghNDDQamPylzd3jSeQ_XntPQfOUto0_zihrdxR6Uvf2xV4CTGPk-P4hkLGK5EqNcGFkqWPClDiAOEO6EpPf_2YhKdGSZ14UUsLHC4VL6cwotqwOvNPzKc8vyDnGCVS_q-C7acgoujf9PQJWZalr98IV0T3xhm1gbkWxNB7GqhdibmutvkM6_W5ja4TWc_CbJoPkmGtDfj3N0Gzr2sP1EP1ARL5Yk-8bu39wlOcmPDv4LP1dpleyaxyoe2dSA379VJsAaafgxL_Gti7RIe5JuIQ",
    "oAuthAccessToken": "ya29.a0AfB_byCA45TvLgTg5yrYJJxVP5gRqZtq3HGzv2vmgdF2EVFsycGOwuQrWR0_nDfFAMVspwTRd9blwsz4qp7-9ncLSKoNlCvnajxjwcB28S5LvEuInKPfyodZ9P2JD7koVjuEmh4V7IiBHuxG0cT8eczE7CweBv7V0gaCgYKAeYSARMSFQGOcNnCzpjVqW_lPyaQDxRcfYHM6g0169"
  }
```